# Disable Users Folder From Sharing through Network Windows 10

Tags: networking

Disable **C:\Users** being Shared over the Network in Windows 10.

Disabling other Folders and its permissions looks easy steps.

[C:\Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfNmd.png)

[Files and Folders of C:\Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPwA6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be Disabled Using PowerShell in Windows 10.

Step 1: To view List of Folders Shared in Network. **Commands $ >** 
[**get-smbshare**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoMUO.png)

Step 2: Remove the Users folder. **Commands $ >**
[**remove-smbshare Users**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf47J.png) 
and Say Yes to All by Pressing Caps **A**.

now the Users Folder Will be remove from the network folder.